# numpy matrix diagonal fill with alternating value

Tags: python, numpy

I am looking for an efficient way to write an alternating value along the diagonal of a matrix. for example ..

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `np.eye` with some slicing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.eye(9)
a[1::2] = 0
print(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.diag` uses a `flat` assignment trick.  It can be streamlined for this case with:

```
a=np.zeros((9,9))
a.flat[10::20]=1
```

That turns out to be substantially faster than the alternatives proposed (so far):

```
In [108]: timeit a=np.zeros((9,9)); a.flat[10::20]=1                                             
1.5 µs ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [110]: timeit np.diag(([1,0]*((k+1)//2))[:k])                                                 
10.1 µs ± 29.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [111]: timeit a=np.eye(9); a[1::2]=0                                                          
6.74 µs ± 20 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

The `eye` approach sets whole rows to 0, but because that's done with broadcasting, it's relatively fast.

Answer (score 0):

This for example:

```
k = 9
np.diag(([1,0]*((k+1)//2))[:k])
```

or

```
np.diag([1,0]*int(np.ceil(k/2)))
```